# Getting intent chooser result

Tags: android, android-intent

My app have a "share" button that starts an intent chooser.
Is it possible to know if the chooser menu was canceled or one of the options where selected?

I tried `startActivityForResult` but the `resultCode` was always 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to know if the chooser menu was canceled or one of the options where selected?

No, sorry. For that, you would need to implement your own chooser.